# Does Rails have a built-in pagination solution?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination

I've noticed that pagination gems like `mislav-will_paginate` are quite popular. Is this because Rails does not have a built-in pagination solution or because the built-in solution is not very good?

Comment: will_paginate is pretty much actually the "built-in" solution these days/

Comment: Seems searchlogic uses will_paginate, so you don't need to use searchlogic to get it. It looks pretty cool, though. http://rdoc.info/github/binarylogic/searchlogic/master/file/README.rdoc#Pagination_(leverage_will_paginate)

Answer (score 28):

In Rails 2.0 the pagination ability of ActionController was removed and turned into a plugin for backwards compatibility called 'classic_pagination'. However, from my searches for a pagination solution for myself the consensus seems to be that using 'classic_pagination' is not optimal.

After watching a couple of podcasts and after several recommendations I opted to try the [will_paginate](http://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/) plugin and haven't looked back. It's fast, easy to use and well-maintained.

I believe that even V2 of Searchlogic recommends its use.

Comment: I came to the same conclusion. The railscasts tutorial on will_paginate was quiet helpful as well.

Answer (score 15):

If you are using Rails 3 Kaminari plugin will be very handy for pagination.
[Github](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari)
[Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/254-pagination-with-kaminari)

Comment: +1 for Kaminari. I was using will_paginate but Kaminari is much nicer.

Answer (score 8):

Rails has built-in pagination, but it's a simple module and not suitable for all needs. Unless you have specific pagination needs in mind though, it should suit most purposes.

[Here's a good article on how to use Rails pagination](http://www.nullislove.com/2007/05/24/pagination-in-rails/)

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend [searchlogic](http://searchlogic.rubyforge.org/). It has pagination built in and many other nices things.

- Easy filtering
- Pagination
- Sorting

And.. for all of that nice helpers.

Code says more than thousand words (**dont get confused by the HAML example, you can use normal erb templates if you prefer them, the code/structure is the same**):

Controller:

```
  def index
    @search = User.new_search(params[:search])
    @users, @users_count = @search.all, @search.count
  end
```

Pagination stuff in  the view:

```
== Per page: #{per_page_select}
== Page: #{page_select}
```

Sort as/by in view:

```
  - unless @users_count.zero?
    %table
      %tr
        %th= order_by_link :account => :name
        %th= order_by_link :first_name
        %th= order_by_link :last_name
        %th= order_by_link :email
      - @users.each do |user|
        %tr
          %td= user.account? ? user.account.name : "-"
          %td= user.first_name
          %td= user.last_name
          %td= user.email
```

Easy, simple and quick filters:

```
  - form_for @search do |f|
    - f.fields_for @search.conditions do |users|
      = users.text_field :first_name_contains
      = users.date_select :created_after
      - users.fields_for users.object.orders do |orders|
        = orders.select :total_gt, (1..100)
    = f.submit "Search"
```

And everything works together, so changing a page and then the sorting, and adding a filter works without losing any of the other settings :).

All you need is in your environment.rb:

```
config.gem "searchlogic"
```

and install it with: `rake gems:install`

Also checkout the [online example](http://searchlogicexample.binarylogic.com/)

Comment: How does this compare to the numerous other pagination solutions? Why choose this over the others?

Comment: Well, the previous thing I used was will_paginate, which used to be the default paginator. 

The beauty of searchlogic is 
a) that everything is integrated (you don't have to get paginator work together filtering/sorting, this is done automatically/magically). And 
b) it's pretty actively developed atm and it looks quite mature.
c) the developer produces very nice and intuitive libraries, I would also recommend his auth library 'authlogic'. In the documentation you'll find some remarks why authlogic is 'better' than the other auth plugins :). 

But just try them out in one of your data views..

Comment: And his blog post: http://www.binarylogic.com/2009/06/09/searchlogic-v2-beta-released/

I still stick with my opinion that searchlogicv1 is a very nice library, and so far it hasn't let me down :).

Comment: Searchlogic is not recommended to be used with Rails3 though.

Comment: what makes you say that? I guess it isn't ready yet, but are there other reasons against a rails3/searchlogic combo?

Comment: @reto It's just not compatible.  There's a port called rd_searchlogic and there's another similar project that I recommend called meta_search.