# Does RoR offer pagination?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination

Does Ruby on Rails offer pagination methods/helpers as a part of frame works?

Comment: State of pagination has not really changed since http://stackoverflow.com/questions/967183/does-rails-have-a-built-in-pagination-solution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It used to offer but it has been discontinued from rails 2.0. Why do you need it when you have an awesome plugin called [Will Paginate](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate)? If you still want to go the ancient way, here is a plugin called [Classic Pagination](https://github.com/masterkain/classic_pagination). Extracted from rails 1.x. But doesn't look like it is being maintained post rails 2.3.4.

Answer (score 3):

There's a new pagination library called [Kaminari](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari). There's a [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/254-pagination-with-kaminari) on it.